# Logical OR not working in regular expression

Tags: regex, regex-alternation

I am working on a big log file whose entries are as follow:

```
-- "GET <b>/fss-w3-mtpage.php</b> HTTP/1.1" 200 0.084 41 "-" "c110bc/1.0" 127.0.0.1:25001  0.084

-- "GET <b>/m/firstpage/Services/getAll</b>?ids=ABCVDFDS,ASDASBDB,ASDBSA&requestId=091fa2b4-643e-4473-b6d8-40210b775dcf HTTP/1.1" 200

-- POST <b>/lastpage/Services/getAll</b>?ids=ABCVDFDS,ASDASBDB,ASDBSA&requestId=091fa2b4-643e-4473-b6d8-40210b775dcf HTTP/1.1" 200
```

And I wanted to extract the part that is bolded out in above sample. Here is the regex that I wrote for the above

```
.*(POST|GET)\s+(([^\?]+)|([^\s]))
```

I want to get the part that is after `GET` or `POST` and until the first occurrence of a space `' '` or a question mark `'?'`.

**Problem**
The logical OR in the later part of the regex is not working.
If I use only

```
.*(POST|GET)\s+([^\?]+)
```

I am getting the correct portion i.e. from GET or POST until the first question mark `'?'`.  Similarly if I use

```
.*(POST|GET)\s+([^\s]+)
```

I am getting the correct portion i.e. from GET or POST until the first space `' '`).

Please can anyone tell me where I am wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the matched group from index 2

```
\b(POST|GET)\s+([^?\s]+)
```

Here is [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nO7jF9/3)

Pattern explanation:

```
  \b                       the word boundary

  (                        group and capture to \1:
    POST                     'POST'
   |                        OR
    GET                      'GET'
  )                        end of \1

  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more times)

  (                        group and capture to \2:

    [^?\s]+                  any character except: '?', whitespace
                             (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more times)

  )                        end of \2
```

Answer (score 4):

> With `[^\?]+` I am getting the correct portion till first question mark,
>   With `[^\s]+` I am getting the correct portion till first space

Because those character classes mean: All characters that are no question marks, or: all characters that are no spaces.

To combine them, you want to say: All characters that are neither a question mark nor a space:

```
[^?\s]+
```

With the OR that you did used it just did try the first (`[^\?]+` - including spaces), which succeeded, and would have backtracked and tried `[^\s]+` (including question marks) instead if the first didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The below regex would match only the strings which are just after to `GET` or `POST` followed by a space or a `?` symbol.

```
(?<=GET |POST )\s*.*?(?= |\?)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/xJ2fP5/2)

You could use capturing groups `()`, inorder to capture the matched strings.

```
(?<=GET |POST )\s*(.*?)(?= |\?)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/xJ2fP5/3)

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
  GET                      'GET '
 |                        OR
  POST                     'POST '
)                        end of look-behind
\s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                         more times)
(                        group and capture to \1:
  .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more
                           times)
)                        end of \1
(?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
                           ' '
 |                        OR
  \?                       '?'
)                        end of look-ahead
```